# How do I extend the margin of the Eclipse source formatter?

Tags: java, eclipse

Whenever I use **Source > Format** in Eclipse, it wraps the line starting at row 80. But my program has a lot of long lines and I'd like to extend its tolerance to 120. I've tried searching for a setting where I can change this but can't find one. Can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find it under **Preferences**->**Java**->**Code Style**->**Formatter**.

Click on the **Edit** button next to the currently active profile, go to the **Line Wrapping** tab and change the **Maximum line width** setting.

Comment: Cool, thanks. The system doesn't allow me to accept it yet, but I'm logging off now. I'll accept later.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Window/Prefences and open Java/Code Style Formatter. Then edit the profile. You can change the margin on the "Line Wrapping" tab ("Maximum line width").